# How to combine two independent likelihood ratio tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let us know that a patient has one of disease A or B. Suppose that we run an experiment to find that the patient has disease A or disease B. The null hypothesis is that the patient has disease A and the alternative hypothesis is that the patient has disease B.

Let the sample that we use for the likelihood ratio test be partitioned into two sets: in the first set, there are $n$ IID observations; and in the second set, there are $m$ IID observations. For example, the first set includes $n$ measurements of the blood pressures and the second set includes $m$ measurements of the blood Oxygen levels. **We also assume that the observations of both sets are mutually independent.**

Let the null hypothesis be accepted if the distribution of the first set ($n$ observations) is $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{0},\sigma_{0}^2)$ and the distribution of the second set ($m$ obervations) is $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^2)$. We reject the null hypothesis if the distribution of the first set ($n$ observations) is $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{3},\sigma_{3}^2)$ and the distribution of the second set ($m$ obervations) is $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{4},\sigma_{4}^2)$.

**Question:** what is the optimal hypothesis test for this problem?

PS. If we had only one set, according to Neyman-Pearson lemma, the optimal test was the the likelihood ratio test $\lambda_0 <\frac{\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^nf'(x_i)}$, where $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are the pdf of normal distributions $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{0},\sigma_{0}^2)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^2)$, respectively.